# AS3- Using 7 byte HEX values as keys in dictionary

Tags: actionscript-3, dictionary, air, hex

I have an AIR application that reads RFID tags. The values of the tag ID's are 7 byte hex values.

There is a limitation on the highest numbers represented accurately within actionscript.
The Number type only works with 53 bit values. The 7byte hex value is 56 bit.

So there is a chance of possibly duplicate keys.

Is there any advantage in using the HEX values themselves as keys for the dictionary?

Or does Flash internally still convert these values to Numbers before using as keys?

Comment: I don't understand how are you going to convert those 7 byte hex values to something that Flash can handle? If Number can't take that much info, in what form do you use them? As far as I know, Dictionary has no convertion at all, as it uses object's address as key and so if you have an unique object, it will be an unique key for your Dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right about this limitation, as3 `Number` type is actually a `Double` precision 64-bit with only 53 bits for the mantissa, but I wonder how do you read the 7 byte value and where do you store it?

There are several as3 `Long` implementations (64 Integer) so you can use it to read and store 7 bit number (but it will still read 8 bytes from the `ByteArray`), but if you don't need the Math for your big number just use `Strings` to read in and use them as a keys for Dictionary.

Anyway Dictionary uses only `Strings` or `Objects` as a keys but not Numbers, so even if as3 had a Long it would be convert to the String.

Comment: Thanks!. Didn't know that about Number not being used as keys